# How do I write unit tests in Cypress? Is that even possible?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, unit-testing, cypress

I am using Cypress with Cucumber to develope a front-end with vue.js using behaviour driven development (BDD). I can already use Cypress for end-to-end testing, but I was also required to create and run unit tests. I could not find anything on the official Cypress website. How can I create and run unit tests for this front-end?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use Cypress for unit testing. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all recipes related to the unit tests in the [official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Unit-Testing).

Let's say you want to unit test math functions from the application's code, you can do so with Cypress:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import math from '../../math'

describe('Unit Test Application Code', function () {
  const { add, divide, multiply, subtract } = math

  before(() => {
    // check if the import worked correctly
    expect(add, 'add').to.be.a('function')
  })

  context('math.js', function () {
    it('can add numbers', function () {
      expect(add(1, 2)).to.eq(3)
    })

    it('can subtract numbers', function () {
      expect(subtract(5, 12)).to.eq(-7)
    })

    it('can divide numbers', function () {
      expect(divide(27, 9)).to.eq(3)
    })

    it('can muliple numbers', function () {
      expect(multiply(5, 4)).to.eq(20)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer, per https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my answer. Let me know what you think. I'm not sure how else improve this answer since the question is very generic.

Comment: Since this question is super generic, the link to the documentation might be better served as a comment, rather than trying to guess what OP is unit-testing.

Comment: @Manuel Abascal I am testing a login logout and registeration web pages. very simple implementaiton with no back end (response is stubbed). how would I go about unit testing the buttons for example? or the input text fields?

Comment: This is too generic to give you a proper answer. I would say read how to do it with Mocha, Chao and Sinon.js, then reimplement the unit tests using Cypress which it uses Mocha, Chai and Sinonjs under the hood